# Add a list to an already stored document in pymongo

Tags: python, insert, pymongo

I've already create a collection in mongo db with several documents and I want to insert to that documents a list of integers. I've found the function update. My code for pymongo is the following:

```
for item in content:
    id = int(item.replace('\n', ''))

    ids = follower_list(id)
    collection.update({'_id':id},{'list_followers':ids})
```

follower_list a function that returns a list of ids. Update it seems to replace the document with new one only containing two fields id and list_followers(initial document containing more fields). I dont want to replace docs I just want to add a new field to the old one. How can i do such a thing?

The mongoDB example here:

```
db.books.update(
{ item: "Divine Comedy" },
{
  $set: { price: 18 },
  $inc: { stock: 5 }
}
```

)

Comment: Why are you using `collection.find` then?

Comment: Hm I didnt clarified well, I forgot to remove cursor.

Comment: I want to add this list into the collection which already has several items, not to create new items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution, `collection.update({ "_id" : id },{"$set": {"list_followers": ids}})`
is what I want here.